# Aggregation relation without parameters

Tags: c#, aggregation

I have some problems with aggregation in C#. Right now, I have the following code:

```
namespace ShapeDrawing
{
    public abstract class Shape
    {
        protected Drawing myDrawing;

        public Shape(Drawing drawing)
        {
            myDrawing = drawing;

        }
    }
    public abstract class Drawing
    {
        public abstract void drawLine();
        public abstract void drawCircle();
    }
}
```

The only problem is, subclasses of Shape has Drawing now as a parameter when one of those classes needs to be instantiated. The only problem is, that Drawing cannot be given as a parameter to those classes (due to some reasoning of the program).

Is there a way to make an aggregation without using Drawing as a parameter for the subclasses of Shape?

[UPDATED TO FIRST ANSWER]

I did that, but then I get the following problem. In one of my subclasses of Shape I have the following method:

```
public override void draw()
        {
            myDrawing.drawCircle(x, y, size);
        }
```

When this method is runned, there is a problem with myDrawing. The error that I get is:

"NullReferenceException was unhandled. An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ShapeDrawing.exe"

How do I fix this?

Regards,
Joren

Comment: The only reason to make a constructor for an abstract class, is to let the derived classes has a common constructor logic (code), so if you want to not let the derived classes do that then no classes will call it and `myDrawing` will never be initialized.

Comment: Now I have the problem that myDrawing is equal to null, because it is not mentioned in any constructor method. Also, myDrawing can never be initialized, because Drawing is an abstract class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you make a constructor that doesn't use Drawing

```
public Shape()
        {}
 public Shape(Drawing drawing)
        {
            myDrawing = drawing;

        }
```